# Registration with google in asp .net application (generitic view)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, google-authentication

Need some help with google autharization: I installed owin package, registered my app on Google (got ClientID and so on) but when i start my app i cant see any button to autharize myself with google (just simple registration i wrote before). I know that I should do smth that provide some view generation for it but dont know what exactly. Read lots of articals in microsort docs but probably miss smth. 
Please help me with this project or just give me references (i have vs 2017) that helped you

Comment: follow : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-configure-google-sign-in-for-Asp-Net-mvc-5-part-sixt/

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `Startup.Auth.cs` to uncomment the `.UseGoogleAuthentication(...)` section and supply your client id and secret that you obtained via registering your app in the google developer console.

`Startup.Auth.cs` should contain something like the following:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(
    new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = "your-clientid.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        ClientSecret = "yourClientSecretHere"
    };
);
```

Assuming you correctly registered your app in the google developer console and that you chose the starting template of a .net framework MVC web application with individual user account authentication scaffolded, this will be the only thing that you need to do. No views changes are necessary. Also, ensure your project is set to run with ssl or it will not work.

There is an easy to follow step-by-step article from Microsoft located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on). You can ignore the small portion about azure hosting as it is not necessary.

Overall, the steps will be:

**1.** Create a new project from the .NET Framework MVC Web Application
    template using Individual User Accounts. (File -> New Project -> ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) -> OK -> MVC -> Change Authentication -> Individual User Accounts -> OK -> OK)

**2.**  Setup project to run as SSL (click on project in solution explorer, look in properties window, set SSL Enabled to true)

**3.**  Register application in the google developer console (https://console.developers.google.com/)

**4.**  Make the small code change I mentioned above in `Startup.Auth.cs`